# Inserting new attribute to a document using MongoDB ( Python )

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm new with MOngoDB ( coming from CouchDB ) and I am having issues with adding new attributes to my documents in MongDB using the MonDB python driver.

For example, I have the following document:

```
{
'_id':123456,
'text':"this is nice"
}
```

And I want to insert a new attribute, for example:

```
{
'_id':123456,
'text':"this is nice",
'created_time':datetime.datetime.now()
}
```

How do I go about adding the created_time attribute to my document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({'_id' : ObjectId(...)}, 
                     {'$set' : {'create_time' : datetime(..) }})
```

Comment: how can I do it from the script? This way it gives ObjectId is not defined

Comment: It's probably a bit late, but... You can use import the following in your python script : `bson.objectid import ObjectId`. Then you simply use it as follows : `c.find({"_id": ObjectId(idAsAString)})`. Another option would be to use **update_one** : `c.update_one({"_id":idAsAString}, {'$set' : {'create_time' : datetime(..) }})`

Answer (score 19):

To insert a new attribute to all existing documents on a MongoDB collection, we can perform this method on our mongo shell:

```
db.collection.update( 
    {}, 
    {'$set': {"new_attribute":"attribute_value"}}, 
    false, 
    true
)
```

- `{}` it's the query criteria, in our case to add our new attribut to all our records, we pass an empty object `{}`
- `{'$set': {"new_attribute":"attribute_value"}}` means that using `$set` operator,  insert on our records a new key `"new_attribute"` that will have this value `"attribute_value"`
- `false` it's `upsert` argument, it tells mongo to not insert a new document when no match is found
- `true` it's `multi` argument, it tells mongo to update multiple documents that meet the query criteria

To find more details check:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 5):

You can update the document using $set.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Or you can get the document, edit it (using python code) and save it back.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Taha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49033121/2218580) you can insert datetime attributes using `currentDate`:

```
db.getCollection("collection-name").update( 
{}, 
{
    $currentDate: {
        "date-field-name": { $type: "date" } // you can also use "timestamp" here
     }
}, 
false, true)
```

or to set a specific date you can use:

```
db.getCollection("collection-name").update( 
{}, 
{
    $set: {
        "date-field-name": ISODate("2020-01-23T04:05:06.007Z")
     }
}, 
false, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

if by any means, the update you were interested on, is solely for the created or updated date-time, you could just add this property when creating your model

```
{
    timestamps: true
}
```

that will add two properties `updatedAt` and `createdAt`
and mongodb will maintain them( created and update time) automatically for you.